# Why C# PictureBox visibility works seldomly?

Tags: c#, visibility, picturebox

Simple stuff. The app puts 12 gifs in 12 different cells in a TableLayoutPanel randomly. All are hidden, but if you click them, they appear.

If I set the visibility from the beginning to true, they show up, but once hidden, no matter what, they don't reappear. Any idea?

Searched high and low, but with no success.

Thanks in advance

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    // Use this Random object to choose random icons for the squares
    Random random = new Random();

    // Create timer int 
    private int counter = 0;

    // Each of these letters is an interesting icon 
    // in the Webdings font, 
    // and each icon appears twice in this list
    List<string> pictures = new List<string>() 
    { 
        "images/baneling.gif",
        "images/baneling.gif",
        "images/scv.gif",
        "images/scv.gif",
        "images/marine.gif",
        "images/marine.gif",
        "images/probe.gif",
        "images/probe.gif",
        "images/zealot.gif",
        "images/zealot.gif",
        "images/zergling.gif",
        "images/zergling.gif"
    };


    // firstClicked points to the first Label control  
    // that the player clicks, but it will be null  
    // if the player hasn't clicked a label yet
    PictureBox firstClicked = null;

    // secondClicked points to the second Label control  
    // that the player clicks
    PictureBox secondClicked = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AssignPicturesToSquares();
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Assign each icon from the list of icons to a random square 
    /// </summary> 
    private void AssignPicturesToSquares()
    {
        // The TableLayoutPanel has 16 labels, 
        // and the icon list has 16 icons, 
        // so an icon is pulled at random from the list 
        // and added to each label 
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            PictureBox currentPicture = control as PictureBox;
            if (currentPicture != null)
            {
                int randomNumber = random.Next(pictures.Count);
                currentPicture.Image = Image.FromFile(pictures[randomNumber]);
                currentPicture.Visible = true; // hide images after generation
                pictures.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer1.Enabled == true)
            return;

        PictureBox clickedPicture = sender as PictureBox;

        clickedPicture.Visible = true;

        if (clickedPicture != null)
        {
            if (clickedPicture.Visible == true)
                return;

            if (firstClicked == null)
            {
                firstClicked = clickedPicture;
                firstClicked.Visible = true;
                return;
            }

            secondClicked = clickedPicture;
            secondClicked.Visible = true;

            // Check to see if the player won
            CheckForWinner();

            if (firstClicked.Text == secondClicked.Text)
            {
                firstClicked = null;
                secondClicked = null;
                return;
            }

            timer1.Start();

        }
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// This timer is started when the player clicks  
    /// two icons that don't match, 
    /// so it counts three quarters of a second  
    /// and then turns itself off and hides both icons 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop the timer
        timer1.Stop();

        // Hide both icons
        firstClicked.Visible = false;
        secondClicked.Visible = false;

        // Reset firstClicked and secondClicked  
        // so the next time a label is 
        // clicked, the program knows it's the first click
        firstClicked = null;
        secondClicked = null;
    }
    /// <summary> 
    /// Check every icon to see if it is matched, by  
    /// comparing its foreground color to its background color.  
    /// If all of the icons are matched, the player wins 
    /// </summary> 
    private void CheckForWinner()
    {
        // Go through all of the labels in the TableLayoutPanel,  
        // checking each one to see if its icon is matched 
        foreach (Control control in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            PictureBox currentPicture = control as PictureBox;

            if (currentPicture != null)
            {
                if (currentPicture.Visible == false)
                    return;
            }
        }

        // If the loop didn’t return, it didn't find 
        // any unmatched icons 
        // That means the user won. Show a message and close the form
        MessageBox.Show("You matched all the pictures in just " + counter + " seconds!","Congratulations");
        Close();
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
    }

    private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: try adding the on click event on the containing table cell

Comment: using the "on click event on the containing table cell" requires a lot more coding that just checking the picture. Is there any way to hide the image without making it invisible (if that makes any sense)?

Comment: No, at least I'm not aware of any. You could change the picture to something identical to your background and then change it back.

Comment: I like that! Testing...

Comment: EDIT: Works wonders, but for some reason, the AssingPicturesToSquares method does not work properly. It does remove items in the list when assigning them, but there are duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You cannot click an invisible control.  The mouse event goes to the TLP instead.  So implement a handler for its MouseClick event to find the control back.  Like this:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    foreach (Control ctl in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls) {
        if (ctl.Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) {
            ctl.Visible = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this block of code, but do not know enough to change the rest of the code to suit this solution :(

Comment: I do not know what you don't know.  If you don't know enough to tell me what you don't know then I don't know how to help you know what you need to know.

Comment: Ok, in other words: instead of adding a block of code, can you help me understand how to implement it or modifying the existing code?

Comment: Sigh.  I do not know what you don't know.  Do not modify any existing code.  Just add the MouseClick event handler for your TableLayoutPanel and make it look like the code I posted.

Comment: How to implement: Step 1: Paste Hans Passant's code into your code (e.g., directly below `tableLayoutPanel1_Paint`).  Step 2: (using the designer), set tableLayoutPanel1's MouseClick event to tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick.